# Transaction started but not ended on database test connection query

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, groovy, bonecp

Recently a bug was noticed in our application which caused the time of the operation to differ from the actual time(we are using current_timestamp() PostgreSQL function instead of passing time from the code). We've looked into it and discovered that the problem had to with some transaction which was starting and was never ended.

The application uses Spring's `DataSourceTransactionManager` which does it job perfectly (every transactional operations are being concluded as expected). Now, the problem seems to be coming from our connection pool lib(BoneCP). We have configured `SELECT 1` query to check database connectivity. And what is actually shown in PostgreSQL log is the following:

```
LOG: execute S_1: BEGIN
LOG: execute <unnamed>: SELECT 1
LOG: execute S_1: BEGIN
LOG: execute <unnamed>: SELECT 1
```

No COMMIT is following any of the connection test statement (further log shows no more BEGIN commands before SELECT 1, but I guess it is because that connection cannot start new transaction while one is already active..

I am wondering if it is some bug or what might be wrong?

Here is servlet-context configuration part file(only posting relevant parts):

```
<bean id="ds" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes" value="5"/>
    <property name="idleMaxAgeInMinutes" value="30"/>
    <property name="lazyInit" value="true"/>
    <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="95"/>
    <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="1"/>
    <property name="partitionCount" value="3"/>
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5"/>
    <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="100"/>
    <property name="releaseHelperThreads" value="3"/>
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false"/>
    <property name="connectionTestStatement" value="SELECT 1;"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sql" class="groovy.sql.Sql">
    <constructor-arg ref="dsProxy"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>

<bean id="dsProxy" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
    <constructor-arg ref="fooDSProxy"/>
</bean>

<bean id="fooDSProxy" class="org.something.Foo" factory-method="createProxy">
    <constructor-arg ref="ds"/>
</bean>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dsProxy"/>
</bean>
```

Where `org.something.Foo` has nothing special, used for logging purposes.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: At a guess, the connectionTestStatement query is being used with a Connection that has autocommit set to false. Given there are no explicit transaction boundaries in your test statement, the DB might be rolling the transaction back rather than committing it (or just leaving it hanging around). Perhaps try adding explicit transaction start and commit to your connection test statement?

Comment: One possible solution is adding COMMIT(as you, Rob suggested) to the test connection statement and it works, I've tested (at least bug disappears and PostgreSQL log reports the end of transaction). But the questions still remain :-|. Where that BEGIN comes from? Is TransactionManager triggered when test query is executed? If it's triggered why in this particular case it does not detect the end of transaction?

Comment: As far as I am aware it is not possible to read data from a DB with there being no transaction, hence why you always see the BEGIN statement. Autocommit means that the transaction will always be committed, but if you turn off autocommit (which you do), then all bets are off as to what happens to the transaction and when. This will differ between individual DB implementations.

Comment: The Java Persistence with Hibernate book has this to say, which is pretty useful: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/Non-transactionalDataAccessAndTheAuto-commitMode?_sscc=t

Comment: Basically, that BEGIN might come from the driver itself? What is written in the Wiki makes sense.. But then it could be a bug of BoneCP, because even with default test connection query (which gets some metadata from database and is much slower then simple select 1) fails to complete transaction.. I suggest you to compile you comments into an answer, I will be glad to accept it.

Comment: Moved above discussion into answer so that it helps others if they come across this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is likely to be due to the autocommit settings on your database connections.

As the name would imply, autocommit automatically wraps each SQL statement in its own transaction and implicitly commits that transaction when the statement has finished. For a lot of production scenarios, autocommit doesn't make sense; you typically want to group together a batch of SQL operations into a single transaction and then either commit or rollback the unit of work.

Your database connection pool settings explicitly turns off autocommit on the connections, therefore I would suggest that your `SELECT 1` connection test statement is being executed in a transaction that has no explicit commit. This would explain why you see the `BEGIN` statement and then no commit afterwards. The way to resolve this is to update your connection test statement to include explicit transaction demarcation e.g. add a `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` to the statement.

In terms of what actually happens to those connections that are not committed, that will depend upon the actual database implementation itself. It might be worth reading up on what 
PostgreSQL will do here.

The Hibernate documentation provides a [pretty good](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/Non-transactionalDataAccessAndTheAuto-commitMode?_sscc=t) explanation of what happens relying upon autocommit. Definitely worth a read.